# $\bf{V}=\bf{L}\rightarrow CH$

Tags: logic, set-theory

I have seen proof of GCH in $\bf{L}$, assuming ZF and the axiom of constructibility. However, I wonder if there is a simpler argument for CH, without the need of Löwenheim-Skolem Theorem and Mostowski Collapsing Theorem? I know that with those theorems we can argue that all constructible subsets of an infinite set $A$ have ranks at most the same cardinality as rank of $A$, and GCH follows.

Comment: I'm confused about the motivation here - the Löwenheim-Skolem and Mostowski Collapse theorems are both very basic results (in my opinion they are more elementary than the definition of L itself!). Is there some reason you think there should be a proof that avoids using these theorems?

Comment: @AlexKruckman Because my professor asked this question and I am kind of stuck on it...

Comment: I don't know how you could prove it using simpler results. Maybe, you could try computing the cardinalities directly? Or a proof by contradicition? Regardless, I suspect a proof using "simpler" machinery will actually end up being quite involved, and much more complicated.

Comment: The proof that $2^{\aleph_\alpha} = \aleph_{\alpha+1}$ holds for any ordinal $\alpha$ in $L$ is essentially verbatim to the proof that $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$ holds. So unless you think that there's a simpler proof for $\mathsf{GCH}$, there's likely not a simpler proof for $\mathsf{CH}$.

Comment: You can proof CH in $L$ via forcing and Shoenfield absoluteness, but these are much more advanced methods.

Comment: @Andreas Can you say a bit more?

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Sure! Say a given real $x$ is in some $L_\alpha$. After collapsing $\alpha$ to $\omega$, there is a real coding a wellfounded initial segment of $L$ to which $x$ belongs. This is a $\Sigma^1_2$ statement, so must be true already in $L$. A witness for this in $L$ codes some $L_\beta$ with $x\in L_\beta$ and $\beta$ countable in $L$. So all reals in $L$ belong to $L_{\omega_1^L}$ and CH follows.

Comment: The argument still uses the Mostowski collapse to convert the real code into a transitive structure, but you do not need condensation or Löwenheim-Skolem.

Comment: @Andreas Ah, nice. Thanks!